# Can maximum modulus theorem be applied in this (real-valued) case?

Tags: algorithms, maximum-principle

I was solving this problem as a programming exercise:

> Given M tiles of $1\times1$ and N tiles of $2\times2$, give an algorithm that returns the (integer) size of the side of the largest possible square that can be built from these tiles.

For example, if $M=8, N=0$ the answer is 2, and if $M=4, N=3$ the answer is 4, etc.

In my solution, I realized that there is a neat way of setting it up as optimization problem:

$$\max_{0\leq x\leq M,0\leq y\leq N}\sqrt{x+4y}$$

And by taking the derivatives we see that there are no extrema inside the domain, hence the max value is on the border, so one combination among $(0,0),~(0, 4N),~(M, 0),~(M, 4N)$ wins  and will give the answer (I intentionally omit some additional steps to show that these 4 points are true candidates for maximum/minimum). This gives a nice $\mathcal{O}(1)$ solution.

If we look at a function $z= \sqrt{x+4y}$ on $D=\{(x,y)| 0\leq x\leq M,0\leq y\leq N\}$, can maximum modulus theorem be applied here? Technically, the theorem works for $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions, but its setup does fit into the described problem.

Comment: That maximum is always $\sqrt{M+4N}$, but that need not be an integer. So your algorithm does not give the correct solution. As an example, for $M=8, N=0$ the maximum is attained at $(x, y) = (8, 0)$, but you cannot build a square from $8$ tiles of size $1 \times 1$.

Comment: @MartinR right, but the answer would be `int(sqrt(8))=2` because the side 2 could be formed with just 4 1x1 squares.

Comment: $\sqrt{x+4y}$ is *increasing* in $x$ and $y$, so your algorithm would always return (the integer part of) $\sqrt{M+4N}$. You don't need a maximum modulus theorem for that conclusion.

Comment: Another example: With $M=1$ and $N=3$ your algorithm computes $\lfloor \sqrt{13} \rfloor = 3$, but I don't see how you can build a $3 \times 3$ square with those tiles.

Comment: You're right, thank you